# SoftLayer API: Getting network usage information for a device

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm experimenting with using the SL API to get information on the usage of a machine.  I'm looking at the metric averageDailyPublicBandwidthUsage.  For baremetal machines it is listed here:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Hardware

This is returning me a float value but two questions on this:

1) What is rate is the float value in?  mb/s, kb/s, b/s?

2) There are several metrics on bandwidth usage as seen in the link I pasted.  Is averageDailyPublicBandwidthUsage an ideal metric for measuring the usage on machines?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the averageDailyPublicBandwidthUsage method should be the average of use in GB/day into the current billing cicle of the server.

The best option is that you use the same method that the Softlayer's control portal uses to its graphs, because you can verify easily if the information that you are retrieving is the correct. So the methods that you are talking about return values which are not the same as the displayed in the control portal so is very triky deal with them.

I recomed you to use this method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/getSummaryData

The method is very flexible you can get information about the Bandwidth usage in a dterminate date and you can specify if you want to see the average usage or the total usage (a sum of all the usage)

e.g. using a REST ful request:

```
POST https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/$MetrictTrackingOBjectId/getSummaryData.json

Payload:

{
"parameters": [
"2017-02-16T00:00:00-00:00",
"2017-02-17T00:00:00-00:00",
[

{
"keyName": "PUBLICOUT",
"summaryType": "average"
}

],
300
]
}
```

To use the method you only need to know the $MetrictTrackingOBjectId associated to the machine for that you only need to use the method getMetricTrackingObjectId

e.g.

```
GET https://$USERID:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/$ServerID/getMetricTrackingObjectId
```

Also you can see all the options that the metickObject has to get infotmation using the method getMetricDataTypes e.g.

```
GET https://$USERID:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/MetrictTrackingOBjectId/getMetricDataTypes.json
```

And finally the data that the getSummaryData method returns  is "bytes used by the interface in the period that you configured in the request"

in this case we used a period of 300 sec in our request. So for example if we got this value from the request: 200856885

> we can convert it like this:
>
> 200856885 * 8 = 1606855080 bits Converting to kbist 1606855080 / 1000
>   = 1606855.08 kbits Converting to Mbist
>   1606855.08 / 1000 = 1606.85 Mbits
>
> 1606.85/ 300 (summary period) = 5.356 Mbps

I hope it helps you, I really recomend you to use this method because can give better information about the usage.

Regards

Comment: Thanks Nelson, I appreciate the thorough and detailed response.  But I'm not very interested in making an additional call to simply get network usage information for a device when there are already several fields that look close to what I need in the baremetal or virtualguest object (nor can I handle the cost of this, we have 10,000+ machines).  I actually don't need a very precise number, nor will I be cross-verifying it.

Comment: I need a metric that tells me a machine is barely being utilized.  Can you help answer what rate the metric I am looking at is in?  Or point me to a more appropriate metric in the baremetal and virtualguest objects?  Thanks again!

Comment: This method maybe can be more suitable for you http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getPublicBandwidthTotal if you just need to know if the machine is being used

Comment: Sorry in this case the metric is the average of use in gigas per day. regards

Comment: Thanks again Nelson.  I'd like to try to use the datatypes available in the hardware and virtualguests objects (no additional method call).  Would it be acceptable to add outboundBandwidthUsage and inboundBandwidthUsage together and say the result is the total bandwidth usage for the past 30 days?  In GB correct?

Comment: It is not he past 30 days its the current billing cycle.

Comment: Thanks Nelson.  I am trying your original/answer suggestion but it is failing for me.  This gives me a proper id (this is ruby):

`id = EM::HttpRequest.new("https://#{username}:#{apikey}@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/475258/getMetricTrackingObjectId", http_options).get`

Comment: But this fails:

`EM::HttpRequest.new("https://#{username}:#{apikey}@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/#{id}/getSummaryData.json", http_options).post(:keepalive => false, :body => {'parameters' => ['2017-02-19T00:00:00-00:00','2017-02-20T00:00:00-00:00', [{'keyName' => 'PUBLICOUT','summaryType' => 'average'}],300]}, :head => {'connection' => 'close'})`

With:
`{"error"=>"Bad request", "code"=>"SoftLayer_Exception_WebService_BadRequest"}`

Comment: for me the same request is working (But I tried using a REST client) maybe there are some issues with your code in ruby I recomend you fisrt try with a RESTclient such as POSTMAN or curl and then try with RUBY also Softlayer has a ruby client maybe that can help you https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-ruby